# How do I improve laptop heat dissipation in docking station?

Tags: laptop, thinkpad, cooling, temperature, overheating

I have a Lenovo laptop that I sometimes use in a docking station.  I am having problems with the laptop running hot (190+F, according to the KDE temperature widget) while under heavy load, especially when docked, where the fan vents are partially blocked by the docking station. The laptop is approximately 5 years old now, and I have dusted the CPU heatsink fan and applied new thermal paste between the CPU and heatsink.

When the laptop runs too long at a high temperature, it shuts off.

What steps can I take to improve the heat/cooling situation?

Answer (score 3):

When you dusted off the heatsink and fan, did you reapply new thermal paste? I've had two laptops that have gradually been getting hotter over the years, despite having a routine of opening and removing dust from the hardware twice a year. Once I decided to remove the old thermal paste (by using Isopropyl Alcohol) and applying some new, and it did wonders.

Turns out that thermal paste dries out over time, so old thermal paste will not be able to get a proper seal when you reassemble the heatsink assembly onto the CPU.

Comment: No, I have not applied new thermal paste. That's an operation I have never done myself.

Comment: @mattm It's fairly simple: Get some lint free wipes of some sort and isopropyl alcohol, then carefulle wipe the CPU until all of it is gone. Make sure you don't apply too much. You only want a very thin layer to act as a boundary layer wit full contact to both CPU and heatsink.

Comment: So I have now applied new thermal paste. The situation has improved when not docked, but with the docking station it will still shut off.